# Route is present but getting result 404

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm trying to send a username and password to the backend. When I sent the request, I got a 404 error for the route.

Backend - `index.js`

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3001;
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/signup", (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  res.json({ username: username, password: password });
  console.log(username, password);
});

app.listen(port, (req, res) => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Frontend - `SignupPage`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const SignupPage = () => {
  const [username, setUseranme] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  async function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    await fetch("http://localhost:3001/signup", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Signup Page</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="username"
          value={username}
          onChange={(e) => setUseranme(e.target.value)}
          autoComplete="off"
        />
        <input
          type="password"
          placeholder="password"
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          autoComplete="off"
        />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SignupPage;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your endpoint to `POST` (instead of `GET`):

```
app.post("/signup", (req, res) => {
  // ...
});
```